# wpf pathsegment /line segment

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need to draw text along lines drawn through pathfigurecollection->pathfigure->linesegement

is there any way to draw text along linesegment...

or is there any way to resolve this.

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Media.Geometry' to 'System.Windows.Media.PathSegment'

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd263097.aspx

Comment: Dead link on a link only answer.